# Sending and receiving SMS

Tags: sms

I'm looking for information how to receive and send SMS using own application. I don't know what devices I should use, what programming language has an appropiate API and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look into [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/).  They have services for sending and receiving SMS messages.

Answer (score 1):

Check out SMSLib at http://smslib.org/

> SMSLib is a programmer's library for sending and receiving SMS messages via a GSM modem or mobile phone. SMSLib also supports a few bulk SMS operators.
>
> SMSLib is distributed under the terms
>   of the Apache v2 license.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [EzTexting](http://eztexting.com) API and [code samples](http://www.eztexting.com/developers/sms-api-code-examples.html) in C#, PHP, Ruby, Java, Perl, Python. Ask me if you have specific questions, I work for the company so would be able to help you with the integration.