# Receiving sms alerts

Tags: sms

I have been asked to build an app for a user to receive text updates to his iphone while he reports traffic updates on his motor bike. Is there a way to code an app that will receive these text messages? Or is there an even simpler way of doing this? He doesn't want to give out his phone number.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending and receiving SMS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355303/sending-and-receiving-sms)